# Как заполнить dataLayer из массива?

Tags: javascript

Мне надо отправить данные для метрики Яндекс.
Есть js массив products каждый элемент которого тоже массив.
Сейчас через цикл foreach пытаюсь заполнят но не получается.
Как правильно заполнят?

```
                        "ecommerce": {
                            "currencyCode": "RUB",
                            "purchase": {
                                "actionField": {
                                    "id" : "TRX987"
                                },
                                "products":[
                                    products.forEach((element) => 
                                        {
                                            {
                                                '"id":'+element['id'],
                                                '"name":'+element['name'],
                                                '"price":'+element['price'],
                                                '"brand": "Brend"',
                                                '"category":'+element['categoty'] ,
                                                '"quantity": 1'
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                    )
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Пример как должен выглядит код

```
dataLayer.push({
    "ecommerce": {
        "currencyCode": "RUB",
        "purchase": {
            "actionField": {
                "id" : "TRX987"
            },
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "25341",
                    "name": "Толстовка Яндекс мужская",
                    "price": 1345.26,
                    "brand": "Яндекс / Яndex",
                    "category": "Одежда/Мужская одежда/Толстовки и свитшоты",
                    "variant": "Оранжевый цвет"
                    "quantity": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "25314",
                    "name": "Толстовка Яндекс женская",
                    "price": 1543.62,
                    "brand": "Яндекс / Яndex",
                    "category": "Одежда/Женская одежда/Толстовки и свитшоты",
                    "variant": "Белый цвет",
                    "quantity": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: как выглядит массив products, который вы перебираете?

Comment: ```470: Array(0)
categoty: "Стеллажи"
id: 470
name: "45°"
price: "96900"
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1644: Array(0)
categoty: "Кровати"
id: 1644
name: "Ял"
price: "134500"
length: 0```

Comment: Лучше в вопрос вставить, так мало понятно. Но видимо у вас на входе массив объектов и есть. Так вы его и выставляйте. Не нужно перебирать. То есть "products": products.   И categoty исправьте на category, буква не правильная

Comment: @PavelNazarian так "products": products сработал. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
products.forEach((element) =>
```

тут нужно добавить return или убрать первые скобки
Как по мне, проще в массив вставить уже готовый результат

```
ecommerce.purchase.products = array..
```

Comment: в forEach добавить return?

Comment: Не совсем понял предложенные вами методы